# How to renew the Keycloak access token in keycloak.js if expired, currently getting error when renewing the token?

Tags: vue.js, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

How to renew the keycloak token using the `keycloak.js` if the token is expired? Currently I have a token which expires in 60 seconds so I have added a method to check if the token is expired if so renew the token for another 60 seconds.

I can see that token is expired but when renewing I am getting error and it does not display the correct error message:

```
// Function to periodically check and renew the Keycloak token
export async function checkAndRenewToken() {
  try {
    const tokenExpired = keycloak.isTokenExpired();

    if (tokenExpired) {
      console.log("Token is expired. Renewing token...");
      try {
        await keycloak.updateToken(30);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          "Failed to refresh token : ",
          +JSON.stringify(error, null, 4)
        );
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.data);
          console.log(error.response.status);
          console.log(error.response.headers);
        } else if (error.request) {
          console.log(error.request);
        } else {
          console.log("Error", error.message);
        }
        console.log(error.config);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error checking/renewing token:", error);
  }
}
```

I am getting the error for this line: `await keycloak.updateToken(30);`. I do not see anything in error message as it shows undefined.

Can someone please help me how to renew the keycloak token using the `Keycloak.js`?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a helper to make the basic conversions. I can't see in your code what's is missing but I think you don't resolve the promise. In my case I am able to flush it with the following code. You can pass the already logged Keycloak object as a parameter, and mix it in your code. It's TS:

```
export const KcAuthHelper = {...more helpers here, isTokenExpired: function (keycloak: Keycloak) {
    return keycloak.isTokenExpired(5)
},
updateTokenIfExpired: function (keycloak: Keycloak) {
    keycloak.updateToken(10)
        .then((refreshed) => {
            return refreshed;
        }, (e) => {
            throw e;
        })
}};
```